# How to deploy my program into a CD?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to deploy my program using vb 2008 express edition into the CD but it has no progress at all and will take a long time when you run the setup.exe to another computer and in the end it will just pops-up an error. I have followed the proper setup procedure on how to publish the program into the CD and was able to successfully published it along with all necessary prerequisites and supporting files.But when you open the setup.exe from the CD using other computer,it won't deploy the program into that computer and will just display a window which gives you 3 buttons saying Details,Retry,Cancel  saying such error after downloading the required files.Does it matter if my OS is Vista and the computer where I'm deploying the program is using XP?What could have been the possible cause for this problem?
How could I possibly resolve this issue?

Comment: If you want any help here, you need to provide more details. What error during what prerequisite?

Comment: Also, it is a small effort to list the selected prerequisties.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

1. Clean the Debug folder of your project.
2. Compile/Test your project again in Debug mode.
3. Burn a cd with the content of your Debug folder.